# Apache-Ignite integration as Hibernate 2nd level cache breaking?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, caching, ignite

I am trying to set Apache Ignite as the second level Hibernate cache provider in my project but i am getting a strange exception.
Configurations are as below:

1. POM.xml

Added

```
<spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
<hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
<ignite.version>1.6.0</ignite.version>
<ignite.version.hibernate>1.0.0</ignite.version.hibernate>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version.hibernate}</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. Spring Hibernate Configuration file

   ```
   <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
   <bean id="sessionFactoryHibernate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
   <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.apache.ignite.cache.hibernate.HibernateRegionFactory</prop>
           <prop key="org.apache.ignite.hibernate.grid_name">hibernate-grid</prop>
           <prop key="org.apache.ignite.hibernate.default_access_type">READ_ONLY</prop>
       </props>
   </property>
   <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entity"></property>
   ```

   3. ignite-configuration.xml

> ```
>     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>        xsi:schemaLocation="
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
>
>     <!-- Basic configuration for atomic cache. -->
>     <bean id="atomic-cache" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration" abstract="true">
>     <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
>     <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
>     <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC"/>
>     </bean>
>
>     <!-- Basic configuration for transactional cache. -->
>     <bean id="transactional-cache" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration" abstract="true">
>     <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
>     <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL"/>
>     <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC"/>
>     </bean>
>
>     <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
>     <!-- 
>         Specify the name of the caching grid (should correspond to the 
>         one in Hibernate configuration).
>     -->
>     <property name="gridName" value="hibernate-grid"/>
>
>     <!-- 
>         Specify cache configuration for each L2 cache region (which corresponds 
>         to a full class name or a full association name).
>     -->
>     <property name="cacheConfiguration">
>         <list>
>             <!--
>                 Configurations for entity caches.
>             -->
> <!--             <bean parent="transactional-cache">
>                 <property name="name" value="com.mycompany.MyEntity1"/>
>             </bean>
>             <bean parent="transactional-cache">
>                 <property name="name" value="com.mycompany.MyEntity2"/>
>             </bean>
>             <bean parent="transactional-cache">
>                 <property name="name" value="com.mycompany.MyEntity1.children"/>
>             </bean>
>   -->
>             <!-- Configuration for update timestamps cache. -->
>             <bean parent="atomic-cache">
>                 <property name="name" value="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"/>
>             </bean>
>
>             <!-- Configuration for query result cache. -->
>             <bean parent="atomic-cache">
>                 <property name="name" value="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"/>
>             </bean>
>         </list>
>     </property>
>
>     </bean>
>
>     </beans>
> ```

4. Entity Class

> ```
> import java.io.Serializable;
>
> import javax.persistence.Column;
> import javax.persistence.Entity;
> import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
> import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
> import javax.persistence.Id;
> import javax.persistence.Index;
> import javax.persistence.Table;
>
> import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
> import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
>
> @Entity
> @Table(name = "USER_TYPE", indexes = {
>       @Index(columnList = "TYPE_SHORT_NAME", name = "TYPE_SHORT_NAME_UNIQUE_idx", unique = true), })
> @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region = "userType")
>
> public class UserType implements Serializable {
>
>   private static final long serialVersionUID = -628308304752474026L;
>
>   @Id
>   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
>   @Column(name = "USER_TYPE_ID")
>   private int userTypeId;
>
>   @Column(name = "TYPE_SHORT_NAME", length = 20, nullable = false)
>   private String typeShortName;
>
>   @Column(name = "TYPE_LONG_NAME", length = 255)
>   private String typeLongName;
>
>   public UserType() {
>   }
>
>   public UserType(int userTypeId, String typeShortName, String typeLongName) {
>       this.userTypeId = userTypeId;
>       this.typeShortName = typeShortName;
>       this.typeLongName = typeLongName;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public int hashCode() {
>       final int prime = 31;
>       int result = 1;
>       result = prime * result + ((typeLongName == null) ? 0 : typeLongName.hashCode());
>       result = prime * result + ((typeShortName == null) ? 0 : typeShortName.hashCode());
>       result = prime * result + userTypeId;
>       return result;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
>       if (this == obj)
>           return true;
>       if (obj == null)
>           return false;
>       if (!(obj instanceof UserType))
>           return false;
>       UserType other = (UserType) obj;
>       if (typeLongName == null) {
>           if (other.typeLongName != null)
>               return false;
>       } else if (!typeLongName.equals(other.typeLongName))
>           return false;
>       if (typeShortName == null) {
>           if (other.typeShortName != null)
>               return false;
>       } else if (!typeShortName.equals(other.typeShortName))
>           return false;
>       if (userTypeId != other.userTypeId)
>           return false;
>       return true;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public String toString() {
>       return "UserType [userTypeId=" + userTypeId + ", typeShortName=" + typeShortName + ", typeLongName="
>               + typeLongName + "]";
>   }
>
>   public int getUserTypeId() {
>       return userTypeId;
>   }
>
>   public void setUserTypeId(int userTypeId) {
>       this.userTypeId = userTypeId;
>   }
>
>   public String getTypeShortName() {
>       return typeShortName;
>   }
>
>   public void setTypeShortName(String typeShortName) {
>       this.typeShortName = typeShortName;
>   }
>
>   public String getTypeLongName() {
>       return typeLongName;
>   }
>
>   public void setTypeLongName(String typeLongName) {
>       this.typeLongName = typeLongName;
>   }
>
> }
> ```

5. IgniteAlphaCachemanager

> ```
> public interface AlphaCacheManager {
> AlphaCache<?, ?> getCache(Class<?> cacheClass);
> }
>
>
>
>
>
>
> import java.util.Map;
> import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
>
> import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
> import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
> import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
>
>
> @Repository
> public class IgniteAlphaCacheManager implements AlphaCacheManager {
>
> private final Ignite ignite;
> private final Map<Class<?>, AlphaCache<?, ?>> caches;
>
> public IgniteAlphaCacheManager() {
>   System.out.println("Init cache...");
>     ignite = Ignition.start("classpath:/spring/ignite-configuration.xml");
>     //ignite = Ignition.start();
>     caches = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
>     initCaches();
> }
>
> private void initCaches() {
>   IgniteCache<Integer, BaseIdea> igniteCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(BaseIdea.class.getName());
>   AlphaCache<Integer, BaseIdea> ideaCache = new IgniteAlphaCache<>(igniteCache);
>   caches.put(BaseIdea.class, ideaCache);
> }
>
> @Override
> public AlphaCache<?, ?> getCache(Class<?> cacheClass) {
>   return caches.get(cacheClass);
> }
>
> }
>
> }
> ```

The exception that i get it below on tomcat startup:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryHibernate' defined in class path resource [spring/databaseContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/cache/CacheProjection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/cache/CacheProjection
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.hibernate.HibernateRegionFactory.buildTimestampsRegion(HibernateRegionFactory.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache.<init>(UpdateTimestampsCache.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheProjection
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
    ... 52 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version for `ignite-hibernate` has to be the same as for other artifacts (1.6.0 in you case).

Note that `ignite-hibernate` is not deployed in Apache Central due to licensing restrictions (Hibernate is licensed under LGPL). You can use the repository provided by GridGain instead:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>GridGain External Repository</id>
        <url>http://www.gridgainsystems.com/nexus/content/repositories/external</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thanks the solved my exception but i ran into another issue now described below.